# Using LoadedLuaScript in StackExchange.Redis for multiple EndPoints/Servers

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, redis-cluster

According to the docs [here](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Scripting), you cache scripts on a server, then use a LoadedLuaScript reference to evaluate them. What is the correct way to evaluate a script when multiple endpoints/servers are configured? Is it correct to cache the first LoadedLuaScript in a dictionary and use that single reference? See pseudo code below.

```
        private IDatabase _db;
        private ConnectionMultiplexer _multiplexer;
        private readonly IDictionary<ScriptType, LoadedLuaScript> _luaScripts = new Dictionary<ScriptType, LoadedLuaScript>;

        public void Initialize(string connection)
        {
            var configuration = ConfigurationOptions.Parse(connection);
            _multiplexer = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(configuration);
            _db = _multiplexer.GetDatabase(0);

            // Need to load on all servers?
            foreach (var endpoint in configuration.EndPoints)
            {
                IServer server = _multiplexer.GetServer(endpoint);

                string scriptCode = ScriptHelpers.GetScript(ScriptType.ReleaseHashsetLock);
                var script = LuaScript.Prepare(scriptCode);
                var loadedScript = script.Load(server);

                // Only keep reference to one loaded script?
                if (!_luaScripts.ContainsKey(ScriptType.ReleaseHashsetLock))
                {
                    _luaScripts.Add(ScriptType.ReleaseHashsetLock, loadedScript);
                }
            }
        }

        public async Task CallScript(object parameters)
        {
            // Correct way to call LoadedScript?
            RedisResult result = await _luaScripts[ScriptType.ReleaseHashsetLock]
                .EvaluateAsync(_db, parameters);

            // TODO
        }
```